# pandas to json using dict to give additional index

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, dictionary

I'm trying to change csv to json.

my pandas dataframe has column named ['number','address','lat','long']

```
number address lat   long
1       blah   37.1  127.2
2       doh    37.2  127.1
```

try to change to json as

```
   [
    {
    "number":1
    "address":"blahblah"
    "location": {
       "lat": 37.1
       "long": 127.2
        }
      }, 
    {
    "number":1
    "address":"doh"
    "location": {
       "lat": 37.2
       "long": 127.1
        }
      },....
    ]
```

I have found out I could use either multiindex on pandas or pandas->dict->json.
 However, the problem is that 'number' and 'address' does not belong to any hierarchy, only 'lat' and 'long' does. Then should I use pandas->dict->json method? Below method failed.

```
df.groupby('number','address',('location')[['long', 'lat']]).apply(lambda g: g.to_dict(orient='record')).to_dict()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: @Junwoo Yun post few lines of you csv data

Comment: posted few lines!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `df` is a variable that stores your dataframe.

```py
import json

df['location'] = df.apply(lambda x:{'lat':x['lat'],'long':x['long']}, axis=1)
df = df.drop(['lat','long'], axis=1)

print(json.dumps(df.to_dict(orient='records'), indent=2))
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "number": 1,
    "address": "blah",
    "location": {
      "lat": 37.1,
      "long": 127.2
    }
  },
  {
    "number": 2,
    "address": "doh",
    "location": {
      "lat": 37.2,
      "long": 127.1
    }
  }
]
```